# C++: Get MAC address of network adapters on Vista?

Tags: c++, windows-vista, mac-address

We are currently using the [NetBios method](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;118623), and it works ok under XP. Preliminary tests under Vista show that it also works, but there are caveats - NetBIOS has to be present, for instance, and from what I've been reading, the order of the adapters is bound to change. Our alternative method - with [SNMPExtensionQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378021(VS.85).aspx) - seems to be broken under Vista.

The question is: do you know of a reliable way to get a list of the local MAC addresses on a Vista machine? Backwards compatibility with XP is a plus (I'd rather have one single method than lots of ugly #ifdef's). Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823553/how-to-get-hardware-mac-address-on-windows these need to be linked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use the [WMIService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394579(VS.85).aspx)? I used it to get the mac-address of a machine in pre-Vista days though.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the cleanest solution to my problem.

Answer (score 21):

This will give you a list of all MAC addresses on your computer.  It will work with all versions of Windows as well:

```
void getdMacAddresses(std::vector<std::string> &vMacAddresses;)
{
    vMacAddresses.clear();
    IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[32];       // Allocate information for up to 32 NICs
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);  // Save memory size of buffer
    DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(      // Call GetAdapterInfo
    AdapterInfo,                 // [out] buffer to receive data
    &dwBufLen);                  // [in] size of receive data buffer

    //No network card? Other error?
    if(dwStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return;

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;
    char szBuffer[512];
    while(pAdapterInfo)
    {
        if(pAdapterInfo->Type == MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)
        {
            sprintf_s(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), "%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x"
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[0]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[1]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[2]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[3]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[4]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[5]
                );
            vMacAddresses.push_back(szBuffer);
        }
        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian,

Thanks for the heads-up; in the meantime I found this link (for XP and later); I guess I'll go either for this or for the WMI solution.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915(VS.85).aspx

Comment: We've used this method above in our main products for several years.  Works good in Vista, 2008, 2003, XP, 2000, ....

Comment: And windows 8 and 8.1

Comment: Works perfectly even in Win10. :)

Answer (score 1):

Old question, already answered, but this is safer code - in case WMI can't be fully initialized.

For getting access to information about your system, here is a minimalist class that tries to stay safe:

NOTE: `ToString`, `convertToUtf8` and `convertFromUtf8` are left as an exercise for the reader. :)

NOTE: I've just shown the *safe* initialization and tear-down of the WMI system, and the basics of getting values from WMI, and getting the MAC Addresses (the question in the OP).

This *came* from working code, but was modified as I pasted it in here.  So it is possible other things got left out that ought to have been included.  Oops.

```
class WmiAccessor
{
public:
    WmiAccessor()
        : _pWbemLocator(NULL)
        , _pWbemServices(NULL)
        , _com_initialized(false)
        , _com_need_uninitialize(false)
        , _svc_initialized(false)
        , _loc_initialized(false)
        , _all_initialized(false)
        , _errors("")
        , m_mutex()
    {
        HRESULT hr;
        hr = ::CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
        switch (hr)
        {
        case S_OK:
            // The COM library was initialized successfully on this thread.
            _com_initialized = true;
            _com_need_uninitialize = true;
            break;
        case S_FALSE:
            // The COM library is already initialized on this thread.
            _com_initialized = true;
            _com_need_uninitialize = true;
            break;
        case RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE:
            // A previous call to CoInitializeEx specified the concurrency model
            // for this thread as multithread apartment (MTA).
            //  This could also indicate that a change from neutral-threaded apartment to
            //  single-threaded apartment has occurred.
            _com_initialized = true;
            _com_need_uninitialize = false;
            break;
        default:
            _com_initialized = false;
            _com_need_uninitialize = false;
            _errors += "Failed to initialize COM.\r\n";
            return;
        }

        hr = ::CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL,
            0 /*RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT*/,
            3 /*RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE*/,
            NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
        // RPC_E_TOO_LATE == Security must be initialized before!
        // It cannot be changed once initialized. I don't care!
        if (FAILED(hr) && (hr != RPC_E_TOO_LATE))
        {
            _errors += "Failed to initialize COM Security.\r\n";
            if (_com_need_uninitialize)
            {
                ::CoUninitialize();
                _com_need_uninitialize = false;
            }
            return;
        }

        hr = _pWbemLocator.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator);
        if (FAILED(hr) || (_pWbemLocator == nullptr))
        {
            _errors += "Failed to initialize WBEM Locator.\r\n";
            return;
        }
        _loc_initialized = true;

        hr = _pWbemLocator->ConnectServer(
            CComBSTR(L"root\\cimv2"), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, &_pWbemServices);
        if (FAILED(hr) || (_pWbemServices == nullptr))
        {
            _errors += "Failed to connect WBEM Locator.\r\n";
            _pWbemLocator.Release();
            _loc_initialized = false;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _svc_initialized = true;

            // Set security Levels on the proxy
            hr = CoSetProxyBlanket(_pWbemServices,
                RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
                RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
                NULL,                        // Server principal name
                RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx
                RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
                NULL,                        // client identity
                EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities
            );
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                _errors += "Failed to set proxy blanket.\r\n";
                return;
            }
        }

        _all_initialized = true;
    }

    ~WmiAccessor()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> slock(m_mutex);

        if (_svc_initialized)
        {
            if (_pWbemServices)
                _pWbemServices.Release();
            _svc_initialized = false;
        }
        if (_loc_initialized)
        {
            if (_pWbemLocator)
                _pWbemLocator.Release();
            _loc_initialized = false;
        }
        if (_com_initialized)
        {
            if (_com_need_uninitialize)
            {
                ::CoUninitialize();
            }
            _com_initialized = false;
            _com_need_uninitialize = false;
        }
        _all_initialized = false;
    }

    // public: must lock
    std::string get_and_clear_errors()
    {
        std::string result = "";
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> slock(m_mutex);
        std::swap(result, _errors);
        return result;
    }

    // public: must lock
    std::string get_string(const std::string& name, const std::string& dflt /*= ""*/)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> slock(m_mutex);
        return _all_initialized ? _string(name) : dflt;
    }

    // public: must lock
    uint32_t get_uint32(const std::string& name, uint32_t dflt /*= 0*/)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> slock(m_mutex);
        return _all_initialized ? _uint32(name) : dflt;
    }


    // similarly for other public accessors of basic types.


private:
    CComPtr<IWbemLocator> _pWbemLocator;
    CComPtr<IWbemServices> _pWbemServices;
    volatile bool _com_initialized;
    volatile bool _com_need_uninitialize;
    volatile bool _svc_initialized;
    volatile bool _loc_initialized;
    volatile bool _all_initialized;
    std::string _errors;
    CComVariant _variant(const std::wstring& name);
    std::string _string(const std::string& name);
    uint32_t _uint32(const std::string& name);
    uint16_t _uint16(const std::string& name);
    uint8_t _uint8(const std::string& name);
    std::vector<std::string> _macAddresses(bool forceReCalculate = false);
    // to protect internal objects, public methods need to protect the internals.
    //
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::vector<std::string> _macs; // unlikely to change, so save them once found.

    // internal: assumes inside a lock
    CComVariant _variant(const std::wstring& name)
    {
        if (!_all_initialized)
            return CComVariant();

        CComPtr<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnum;
        CComBSTR cbsQuery = std::wstring(L"Select " + name + L" from Win32_OperatingSystem").c_str();
        HRESULT hr = _pWbemServices->ExecQuery(
            CComBSTR(L"WQL"), cbsQuery, WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY, NULL, &pEnum);
        CComVariant cvtValue;
        if (FAILED(hr) || !pEnum)
        {
            std::wstring wquery(cbsQuery, SysStringLen(cbsQuery));
            _errors += "Failed to exec WMI query: '" + convertToUtf8(wquery) + "'\r\n";
            return cvtValue;
        }
        ULONG uObjectCount = 0;
        CComPtr<IWbemClassObject> pWmiObject;
        hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pWmiObject, &uObjectCount);
        if (FAILED(hr) || !pWmiObject)
        {
            _errors
                += "Failed to get WMI Next result for: '" + convertToUtf8(name) + "'\r\n";
            return cvtValue;
        }
        hr = pWmiObject->Get(name.c_str(), 0, &cvtValue, 0, 0);
        if (FAILED(hr))
        {
            _errors
                += "Failed to get WMI result value for: '" + convertToUtf8(name) + "'\r\n";
        }
        return cvtValue;
    }

    // internal: assumes inside a lock
    std::string _string(const std::string& name)
    {
        if (!_all_initialized)
            return "";

        CComVariant cvtValue = _variant(convertFromUtf8(name).c_str());
        std::wstring wValue(cvtValue.bstrVal, SysStringLen(cvtValue.bstrVal));
        std::string sValue = convertToUtf8(wValue);
        return sValue;
    }

    // internal: assumes inside a lock
    uint32_t _uint32(const std::string& name)
    {
        if (!_all_initialized)
            return 0;

        CComVariant cvtValue = _variant(convertFromUtf8(name).c_str());
        uint32_t uValue = static_cast<uint32_t>(cvtValue.lVal);
        return uValue;
    }

    // similarly for other internal access of basic types.

    // internal: assumes inside a lock
    std::vector<std::string> _macAddresses(bool forceReCalculate /*= false*/)
    {
        if (!_all_initialized)
        {
            return _macs; // it will still be empty at this point.
        }
        if (forceReCalculate)
        {
            _macs.clear();
        }
        if (_macs.empty())
        {
            // hr == 0x80041010 == WBEM_E_INVALID_CLASS
            // hr == 0x80041017 == WBEM_E_INVALID_QUERY
            // hr == 0x80041018 == WBEM_E_INVALID_QUERY_TYPE
            CComBSTR cbsQuery = std::wstring(L"Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter").c_str();
            CComPtr<IEnumWbemClassObject> pEnum;
            HRESULT hr = _pWbemServices->ExecQuery(
                CComBSTR(L"WQL"), cbsQuery, WBEM_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnum);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                _errors += "error: MacAddresses: ExecQuery('"
                           + convertToUtf8((LPWSTR)cbsQuery) + "') returned "
                           + ToString(hr) + "\r\n";
            }
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                ULONG fetched;
                VARIANT var;
                IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
                while (pEnum)
                {
                    hr = pEnum->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &fetched);
                    if (0 == fetched)
                        break;

                    std::string theMac = "";
                    VariantInit(&var);
                    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"MACAddress", 0, &var, 0, 0);
                    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                    {
                        switch (var.vt)
                        {
                            case VT_NULL: break;
                            case VT_BSTR:
                                theMac = (var.bstrVal == NULL)
                                       ? ""
                                       : convertToUtf8(var.bstrVal);
                                break;
                            case VT_LPSTR:
                                theMac = (var.bstrVal == NULL)
                                       ? ""
                                       : (const char*)var.bstrVal;
                                break;
                            case VT_LPWSTR:
                                theMac = (var.bstrVal == NULL)
                                       ? ""
                                       : convertToUtf8((LPWSTR)var.bstrVal);
                                break;
                            // _could_ be array of BSTR, LPSTR, LPWSTR; unlikely, but ....
                            case VT_ARRAY | VT_BSTR:
                            case VT_ARRAY | VT_LPSTR:
                            case VT_ARRAY | VT_LPWSTR:
                                _errors += "warning: MacAddresses: unexpected array of addresses";
                                _errors += "\r\n";

                                // yet another exercise for the reader :)
                                break;
                            default:
                                _errors += "error: MacAddresses: unexpected VARIANT.vt =  "
                                       + ToString(var.vt) + "\r\n";
                                break;
                        }
                        // local loopback has an empty address?
                        if (!theMac.empty())
                        {
                            _macs.push_back(theMac);
                        }
                    }
                    VariantClear(&var);
                    pclsObj->Release();
                }
            }
        }
        return _macs;
    }

...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

GetAdaptersInfo() is the official method, it enumerates all adapters even ones that are disconnected.
See this post for example code [codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/I-N/network/networkinformation/article.php/c5451/)

Comment: Incorrect. GetAdaptersInfo() can not enumerate adapters that are disabled. The code guru article even states this fact:

"Finally it also works if your NICs are not connected to valid networks (eg. wires are not even hooked up), but the NICs do have to be "enabled" in Windows"

Comment: Furthermore, a card with the TCP/IP protocol disabled will not be detected by GetAdaptersInfo().

Comment: GetAdaptersInfo does not enumerate disabled adapters

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#include <Assert.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "iphlpapi.lib")


char* getdMacAddresses()
{

    IP_ADAPTER_INFO AdapterInfo[32];       // Allocate information for up to 32 NICs
    DWORD dwBufLen = sizeof(AdapterInfo);  // Save memory size of buffer
    DWORD dwStatus = GetAdaptersInfo(      // Call GetAdapterInfo
        AdapterInfo,                 // [out] buffer to receive data
        &dwBufLen);                  // [in] size of receive data buffer

    //Exit When Error 
    if (dwStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return "ERROR";

    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pAdapterInfo = AdapterInfo;
    char szBuffer[512];
    while (pAdapterInfo)
    {
        if (pAdapterInfo->Type == MIB_IF_TYPE_ETHERNET)
        {

            sprintf_s(szBuffer, sizeof(szBuffer), "%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x"
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[0]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[1]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[2]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[3]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[4]
                , pAdapterInfo->Address[5]
                );

            return szBuffer; 

        }


        pAdapterInfo = pAdapterInfo->Next;

    }

    return "ERROR";
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this going to address the problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use WMI on both XP and Vista, there are a number of examples online. e.g: 
[Use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) to get a MAC Address](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/WMI.aspx)

Comment: The OP is for `C++`, and your linked answer is `VB .NET` -- not a very close match.  Also, on _some_ XP systems, WMI is disabled or not installed at all.  Be sure to test the HRESULTS that come back from the calls so you know if it is fully initialized or not.